# Help identifying fraud vector

Tags: payments, wallets

I would like help understanding how I was defrauded.

I recently found out one of my wallets was drained. I'm curious if anyone can help me understand how it happened? It doesn't make any send to me since I didn't post my private key anywhere. It looks like a new wallet was created and the attacker incrementally drained the funds out of my account. I understand I am SOL, just trying to educate myself on the "how it happened" so I can avoid any mistake in the future.

This is the account that was drained: https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GD4635U7OIXJNNLN3JVPFEUCHUYH3GLVIG4Y2W5N6YU65NFAZYRG345W

This is the account that stole it all:
https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GDGQQJXDGTH7QZPM3VYDD4GQTGQAQH3BP4NHLRWH2JGNIVYNJUQPDUCK

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.